# Problems with Border Shadow on Resizing

Tags: .net, xaml, .net-6.0, maui

I'm working on an app using MAUI that displays a series of expandable cards that each contain data. The cards are instances of a control template that looks like this:

```xml
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:MovieDisplay.Controls"
             x:Class="MovieDisplay.Controls.Card"
             x:Name="CardHeader"
             Background="transparent">

    <Border x:Name="border"
            BindingContext="{x:Reference CardHeader}"
            BackgroundColor="{Binding CardBackground}"
            Padding="{Binding Padding}"
            Margin="{Binding Margin}"
            StrokeThickness="1.5"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 40">
        <Border.Shadow>
            <Shadow Brush="Black"
                    Radius="5"
                    Opacity="1"/>
        </Border.Shadow>
        <c:Expander> 
            <c:Expander.Header>
                <!-- Bind title to header -->
            </c:Expander.Header>
                <!-- Bind content -->
            <c:Expander.Footer>
                <Image x:Name="Chevron" 
                       Source="chevron_down.png" 
                       HeightRequest="40" 
                       WidthRequest="40" 
                       VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <Image.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger TargetType="Image">
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type c:Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                                                  Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <c:RotateAction StartsFrom="0"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <Setter Property="Scale" Value="1"/>
                            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <c:RotateAction StartsFrom="180" />
                            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </Image.Triggers>
                </Image>
            </c:Expander.Footer>
        </c:Expander>
    </Border>
</ContentView>
```

I implement this template in my main file using:

```xml
            <controls:Card x:Name="CardTemplate"
                           Title="STANDING THERE"
                           Subtitle="i realize that you were just like me trying to make history"
                           TitleStyle="{StaticResource DefaultTitle}"
                           SubtitleStyle="{StaticResource DefaultSubtitle}"
                           CardBackground="white"
                           Padding="16,16"
                           Margin="0,3,0,3"
                           CornerRadius="40"/>
```

The cards it creates look like this:
[Picture of cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kimn.png)

The problem I am having is with the `<Border.Shadow>` in the template. When the app first boots, the shadow is drawn correctly around the shape of the card, but when the card expands the shadow fails to update.

Here's when the card starts expanded:
[Shadow errors on expanded card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWK9d.png)

Here's when the card starts closed:
[Shadow errors on closed card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOirA.png)

I've been looking at ways of refreshing or redrawing the shadow, but haven't found anything that has worked. What do you think I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo?

Comment: Sure! Here you go: [https://github.com/Tyler-Duckworth/MauiBorderShadow](https://github.com/Tyler-Duckworth/MauiBorderShadow)

Comment: Thanks for your update! I've reproduced the issue and turns out the Border.Shadow only works in Android and iOS platform, for windows platform, it's not working! It's a potential issue, there's a similar issue in this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8150), please follow up in that link. Thanks!